# Suppose you have a 10 x 5 grid. How many ways can you get from the lower left-hand corner to the upper right-hand corner?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I thought the answer would have something to do with the binomial coefficient. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_path#Combinations_and_NE_lattice_paths) Wikipedia page seemed to indicate that the number of ways from $(0,0)$ to $(n,k)$ is equal to $\binom{n+k}{n}$. Does this still work if the table is not a square table, with the same number of rows as columns? Would I be able to say the answer is $\binom{15}{10}=3003$?
The grid by the way is 10 squares across and 5 squares tall. The only restrictions are that you can't walk back on your own path (so the ways are finite), you can move only one step at a time, you can only move along the lines of the grid.

Comment: The answer depends on the ways in which you are allowed to move. Are you allowed to move only one unit at a time? Can you move diagonally? Can you move in any direction? Can you move back to a position that you were previously at? Without any additional restrictions, there are an infinite number of ways since there is nothing stopping you from moving back to a position you've been before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking the moves as a sequence of binaries and assuming we can only move 10 times right and five times up.
$1$ = right, $0$=up
We have binary word ($a_0,a_1,....a_{15}$) where $a_i \in \{0,1\}$, having 10 x $1$ and 5 x $0$

The amount of ways you can set 10 x $1$s to the 15-length sequence is $\binom{15}{10}=3003$,
so with the assumptions, you're correct.